# Booking Appointments in A Public Calendar in outlook Using VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I was just wondering if anyone can help me. I am very new to coding and am trying to create a macro that books full day events in a shared outlook calendar. I have searched the depths of the internet and cant seem to find anything.

I am trying to use the below code which picks up the from and to date in a range on the work book and book into the following shared calendar "\UK Public Folders\Customer Services\UK Customer Services Calendar" in outlook but I am just not having any luck defining the folder path. can anyone help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateOutlookAppointment()

Dim strCategory As String, strTopic As String, strLocation As String, strStartdate As String, strStarttime As String
Dim strEnddate As String, strEndtime As String, strDuration As String, bolWholeday As Boolean, bolReminder As Boolean, lngReminderMinutes As Long
Dim bolPlaysound As Boolean, strParticipants As String, bolRespondNecessary As Boolean, strNote As String


Dim strCategory As String, strTopic As String, strLocation As String, strStartdate As String, strStarttime As String
Dim strEnddate As String, strEndtime As String, strDuration As String, bolWholeday As Boolean, bolReminder As Boolean, lngReminderMinutes As Long
Dim bolPlaysound As Boolean, strParticipants As String, bolRespondNecessary As Boolean, strNote As String

Dim olApp As Object
Dim objCal As Object
Dim olCal As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objCal = olApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9)
Set olCal = objCal.Items.Add(1)



'=============================================================
'Entries for appointment
'=============================================================
strCategory = "Holiday"
strTopic = Range("Employee3")
strLocation = ""
strStartdate = Range("FROM1")
strStarttime = "09:00"
strEnddate = Range("FROM2")
strEndtime = "09:00"
strDuration = "60"    'If duration of appointment necessary, remove comment for "Duration" below
bolWholeday = True
bolReminder = True
lngReminderMinutes = 10
bolPlaysound = True
strParticipants = Range("A8").Value
bolRespondNecessary = False
strNote = "Your On Holiday"
'=============================================================

'Create appointment
With olCal
    .Categories = strCategory
    .Subject = strTopic
    .Location = strLocation
    .Start = strStartdate & " " & strStarttime
    .End = strEnddate & " " & strEndtime
    '.Duration = strDuration   'If duration is given about, remove comment
    .AllDayEvent = bolWholeday
    .ReminderSet = bolReminder
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = lngReminderMinutes
    .ReminderPlaySound = bolPlaysound
    .Recipients.Add strParticipants
    .ResponseRequested = bolRespondNecessary
    .Body = strNote
    .Display
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set olCal = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

many thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

What is the error code or error message?
Are you using *On Error Resume Next* to hide error messages? Do not!

Comment: nothing happens when it runs and no errors pop up after. I have tried to debug it but it just runs through the code. so cant work out what I have done wrong. Due to inexperience with coding I dont really know where to start

Comment: Well, set a breakpoint somewhere after start (F9). When hit, step through the code with F8.